# Html.Decoded &shy; is problematic in string functions

Tags: c#, string, replace

```
string local= HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(GetLocalizedSupportPhone()).Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "");
```

I am getting a string :

```
"0&shy;12&shy;4 41&shy;481&shy;73"
```

from the `GetLocalizedSupportPhone()` method. The Html Decode method returns:

```
"0-12-4 41-481-73"
```

I  have a list of phone numbers like:- `"01244148173"`, `"01244148173"`, etc which are plain integers without any space character or html character.

Problem scenario:- All i want to do is to get decoded ***local*** string ("`0-12-4 41-481-73`"), replace the `&shy;` as well as `" "` with empty `string` character and compare the resultant ***local*** string with the list items. If a similar list item exists, then remove that particular list item.

But strangely, the `.Replace()` method replaces space character with blank string but is unable to replace `"-"` with empty `string`.

I am just curious why is it happening? Why ANY OF THE STRING METHODS (like I tried with `.split()` ) can not detect `"-"`?

Comment: No, it should not be the issue... string methods should work find with replace. But how do check that you cannot replace your string "-" with empty `string`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different types of hyphens. `&shy;` is a soft hyphen.  Specifically the soft hyphen is 173 and the hyphen on your keyboard is 45.

Try this instead.

```
var r = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("0&shy;12&shy;4 41&shy;481&shy;73")
                   .Replace((char)173, ' ')
                   .Replace(" ", "");
```

That will replace the soft hyphen with a space and then your second replace will get rid of that.

Another option would be to use a regular expression to remove all non-numeric values.

```
Regex nonNumeric = new Regex(@"\D");
var r = nonNumeric.Replace(
    HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("0&shy;12&shy;4 41&shy;481&shy;73"), 
    string.Empty);
```

Comment: Wow!
i had this thoght that the hyphens are different but could never think of the solution :)
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

This might help if you're just looking to strip spaces and soft hypens from a string without having to deal with HTML decoding:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\u00ad| ");
var result = regex.Replace(stringWithSoftHyphens, string.Empty);
```

I tried doing this with Trim((char)173) but it (and methods like Split) do not seem to be able to handle the soft hyphen character like the Regex class can.

Comment: Or directly to change the shy to a minus sign:
string = Regex.Replace(string, @"\u00ad", "-");